# Dynamic RedirectUri in identityserver3

Tags: identityserver3, thinktecture-ident-server

I have a single page application in angularjs 1.x. I am using IdentityServer3 for user authentication.

After successful login, user is redirected to home page of my single page application. This redirecturi is set in startup.cs of SPA Project.

But when user types a url which only an authenticated user can access, identityserver login page will appear. After login user will be redirected to home page but I want user to be redirected to url entered by him after successful login.

Can we achive this? Or the redirecturi is fixed when we use identityserver?

Answer (score 0):

The most common way to do this is to embed the information in the state variable when redirecting to the IdServer. This way, on the callback, you have some information on how to redirect the user after you get the callback from IdServer. 
If you use the [OIDC client library](https://github.com/IdentityModel/oidc-client-js) it handle these things for you.